# MySQL utilities caching_sha2_password authentication method is not compatible with caching_sha2_password method

Tags: mysql, recovery, frm

I have a set of databases from a MySQL version older than my current Innodb version "8.0.34 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)". What I did was copy and paste the files from the ...MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data folder into a backup folder, update to my current version of MySQL and I'm trying to use MySQL Utilities with the command "mysqlfrm --server= [connection parameters] scheeme.frm > scheeme.sql" to convert the files "scheme.frm" containing the table definition to a .sql file. Running this returns an error: "mysqlfrm: error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported."

My possible solution has been to check and change the authentication method of my root user from caching_sha2_password to mysql_native_password as follows:

ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

However I keep getting the same error. mysqlfrm.exe: error: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported.

It is strange that the latest version of MySQL utilities current "1.6.5" does not support caching_sha2_password. Being an authentication method added from very previous versions of MySQL. Is there any other solution to my problem?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to use deprecated software.

MySQL Utilities was last released in 2017-01-25.

The caching_sha2_password authentication plugin was introduced in MySQL 5.7.23, 2018-07-27 — six months after the last release of MySQL Utilities.

MySQL Utilities was deprecated after that. Subsequent development of MySQL administrative tools is implemented in MySQL Shell.

The `mysqlfrm` tool that was included in MySQL Utilities wouldn't be useful on MySQL Server 8.0 anyway, because `.frm` files no longer exist given the new implementation of data dictionary with `.sdi` files (see https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-80-all-you-need-to-know-about-sdi).

There's a community tool to convert `.sdi` files to DDL, which is analogous to what `mysqlfrm` did in earlier versions of MySQL: https://github.com/altmannmarcelo/sdi2ddl